# How To Add HTML Code To Asp Button's Text Attribute

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add a symbol for a button's text but this shows no text. What's the correct way?

The symbol is an arrow - [here](http://character-code.com/arrows-html-codes.php).

```
<asp:button id="btnAdd" runat="server" class="next"/>
```

**CSS:**

```
.next
{
   content = &#10095;
   width:50px;
}
```

When I say `Text='&#10095;'`, it shows a '?' symbol

Comment: the entity you are using doesn't render, try this arrow: `&#8594;` or select another from the page you provided

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one:

```
<asp:button id="btnAdd" runat="server" class="next" Text="&#10095;"/>
```

Comment: I've checked it in WebForms project. It works perfectly. Maybe you have a problem with your fonts? Try to add css-property "font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;

Comment: also using chrome and you are correct  &#10095; is not working as expected, showing box, not the one specified

Comment: Heh, in Chrome it doesn't work. In IE11 - works. I'm sure that the reason is in fonts. Let me check...

Comment: I checked in FF. It works. But not in chrome. I also included Font-Names="Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif"

Comment: @Ruby It's all browser dependent, so if it is your requirement, better to use image

Comment: Open this page http://character-code.com/arrows-html-codes.php in Chrome and look for 10095 - it displays a square box

Comment: Have a look on this topic - http://superuser.com/questions/232636/displaying-unicode-on-chrome-vs-firefox?rq=1 Agree with vikas - the easiest way is to use an image

Comment: opening in chrome...simple yet clever. how could i not think of that. Yes, I have to look at other not so simple ways now.:). Thank you all again

Answer (score 2):

It is easiest to set the `Text` [attribute of the asp:button](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/385641/how-to-change-button-text-in-asp-net-Dynamically)

```
<asp:button Text="&#8594;" .../>
```

EDIT:

the entity you are using doesn't render, try this one: `&#8594;` →

If you really need a css solution:

`content` is only a valid rule when using the `:before` or `:after` pseudo-selectors, note: you're not really setting the content of the button, you're adding a text element after the button! Also, if using `content`, [you need to use unicode](http://www.evotech.net/articles/testjsentities.html)

```
.next:after{
   content: "\25BA";
}
```

http://css-tricks.com/css-content/

Comment: I noticed the website you linked uses 'Source Sans Pro' font. Probably the default font doesn't include that character. However it still doesn't work for me in chrome even with 'Source Sans Pro' font

Comment: if you'd like to try `source sans pro`, you can follow these instructions http://www.google.com/fonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Source+Sans+Pro

Comment: Thank you. But unfortunately, this app is not online.

Comment: I see, in that case you can download the font and host it locally. you can download `source sans pro` from the earlier link and here are some basic instructions for hosting it yourself http://www.miltonbayer.com/font-face/

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="submit" value="&#10137;">
```

In `ASP.NET`

```
<asp:Button ID="btnLogin" Text="Login &#10137;" runat="server" />
```